# How to move x-axis position to top in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I know it sounds stupid but I'm having a hard time moving the x-axis to the top in Spotfire. I do not know if it is possible. I would like the graph like this:
[Click to view an example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pdIm.jpg)

It's not about moving the label, but x-axis position.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @guillermochamorro
I have a common scatter plot, with the y-axis on the left and the x-axis on the bottom. I could not evolve beyond that. I checked the axis settings and properties and did not find this option. I looked at forums but always asking about the labels and not about the position of the axis. Take a look at the image I put.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the plot and go to properties. On Y-axis, check the Reverse scale box.